# Javascript programming model to organize Web Applications

Tags: javascript

I have been programming in PHP and C# for a long time, but I have done very little Javascript.
For server side programming I use MVC, which is very nice and my code is neatly organized.

Now, for Javascript, when I write code, I usually screw things up. It becomes something like spaghetti code. I don't know how to organize my code.

Can anyone please help me with any resource, book, or anything which might help with writing neat and organized Javascript code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tip for javascript newbie coming from PHP and C# - javascript has function scope, not curly brace scope.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place for this question. There isn't a *correct* answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mention that you have been programming in PHP and C# for a long time.  Take your code organization experience and apply it to your javascript.

**Couple of frameworks**

Google's Closure tools -

http://code.google.com/closure/

If Google uses it to organize Gmail and Google Docs, then it should work for most large applications.

Also, Yahoo! YUI is good too -

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/

http://yuilibrary.com/

And backbone.js (not as "big" as Google or Yahoo) -

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone

**Decent Book**

For me, writing javascript unit test helps me stay organized -

Test-Driven JavaScript Development

[http://www.amazon.com/Test-Driven-JavaScript-Development-Developers-Library/dp/0321683919/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321683919)

Comment: Google's Closure tools has some faults, and in specific conditions will insert errors in the code.

Comment: @Bakudan - absolutely (although I would not call them faults). The Closure docs and "Closure: The Definitive Guide" do a good job explaining certain issues - http://www.amazon.com/Closure-Definitive-Guide-Michael-Bolin/dp/1449381871/

Comment: I have been working on backbone since @KrisKrause posted this answer.
I should say, it is really great and it helps organize code very neatly. Thanks.

Comment: And one more thing, http://peepcode.com/ has a great (non-free) screencast on Backbone.

Answer (score 3):

Write modular code. It's not very hard.

Personally I recommend you write very many modules and user a building process and package manager to append them into one.

I use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) for that.

```
// DOM-utils.js

module.exports = {
  // util methods
}

// some-UI-Widget.js
var utils = require("DOM-utils"),
  jQuery = require("jQuery");

// do ui logic

module.exports = someWidget
```

I would go further and recommend you use a [mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) (see [mediator](https://github.com/tommedema/mediator)) to keep all your code loosely coupled.

See this [example application](https://github.com/Raynos/ExpressArchTest/tree/master/src/client/js)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript: The Good Parts

[http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

Plus any Crockford videos from YUI Theater.

http://yuilibrary.com/theater/

Comment: Don't even bother: JSTGP doesn't say diddly about code organization. In fact, it doesn't say very much at all.

Comment: @PeteWilson JSTGP says all you need to know about JavaScript. It's a very good and concise book

Comment: It might be a good js book, but it doesn't go deep into organization of js code, and it's not just this book, its 95% of js books.

Comment: @JSTGP: while (1) { always use semicolons; (2) always use braces in conditionals; (3) ***buy me!***; }

Comment: @Raynos -- It is certainly concise. The advantage is that I don't have to wade through all that much BS to get to the end.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if a library suggestion is what you're after, but we started using Mootools as our base js library. [Mootools' Class](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class) system is amazing for creating a class hierarchy. It's helped our team out immensely in keeping all our code organized.

If you're looking for simpler object-oriented solutions and need inheritance there are many, many libraries offering this. Two of my favorite are [klass](https://github.com/ded/klass) and [selfish.js](https://github.com/Gozala/selfish).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent reference.  It is difficult to avoid spaghetti in Javascript at times.  Also be aware that Javascript does NOT support Polymorphism.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/javascript-best-practices/

Comment: It does not support truly polymorphic methods. This killed me one day writing an app with two methods having different input signatures.  Being a longtime Java programmer, it didn't dawn on me until I did some interactive debugging just exactly what was going on.  http://javascript.about.com/library/blpolyfunc.htm

Answer (score 1):

[Alex MacCaw](http://alexmaccaw.co.uk/) wrote a book just out, [JavaScript Web Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144930351X) that covers some of the JavaScript frameworks available. MacCaw is the creator of [Spine](http://maccman.github.com/spine/), another MVC JavaScript framework (like backbone.js is). There are tutorials on the Spine site covering how to use it. Additionally, if you're interested in backbone.js, [Peepcode](http://peepcode.com/) currently has two screencasts (not free) that cover using it.

Answer (score 1):

Check these articles out and you will get good ideas on how to use OOP in JavaScript:

http://www.cyberminds.co.uk/blog/articles/polymorphism-in-javascript.aspx

http://www.cyberminds.co.uk/blog/articles/how-to-implement-javascript-inheritance.aspx

Regards,

Joe